# Get Campaigns from owned Ad accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to use the facebook api to retrive campaigns from ad accounts linked to our business account, when I got that part done I want to retrieve adgroups from the campaigns (but that's another thing)

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\Business;


$access_token = '';
$app_secret = '';
$app_id = '';
$businessId = '';

$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());
$fields = array(
    'name',
    'objective',
);
$params = array(
    'effective_status' => array('ACTIVE','PAUSED'),
);
$ownedAccounts = (new Business($businessId))->getOwnedAdAccounts($fields, $params)->getResponse()->getContent();

foreach ($ownedAccounts['data'] as $ownedAccount) {

    $hmm = new AdAccount($ownedAccount['id']);
    try {
        $hmm->getCampaigns();
        echo "Ok for : ". $ownedAccount['name'] . "\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Failed for : ". $ownedAccount['name'] . "\n";
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is I keep getting (#200) Permissions error.

Comment: So what permissions does your access token include then? Do they match the permissions you need, according to the documentation of the endpoint you are using?

Answer (score 0):

the system user of the app did not have access to the ad accounts, adding them accounts to the system user fixed the issue